# How to determine whether a homogeneous polynomial in two variables is positive definite?

Tags: polynomials, homogeneous-equation

I have a polynomial in two variables of order 4 that is homogeneous. Is there any method for determining its sign definitiveness?

Cheers!

Comment: How is sign definitiveness defined?

Comment: Hi, by sign definitiveness I meant that 

P(x1,x2) > 0 or P(x1,x2) < 0, for any x_1, x_2 where P(x1,x2) is a homogeneous polinomial in two variables.